# Why is logistic equation called "logistic"?

Tags: terminology, math-history

[The logistic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) solves [the logistic ODE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function#Logistic_differential_equation) which is the continuous version of [the logistic map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map).

However, I was not able to find why any of these things are called "logistic".

Comment: Doesn't the first link you supply answer the question? "A logistic function or logistic curve is a common sigmoid function, given its name in 1844 or 1845 by Pierre François Verhulst who studied it in relation to population growth."

Comment: The term is very old, and has been used, for example, to mean arithmetic. Verhulst introduced the term for the curve that is often used to model constrained growth. I believe it is not known why.

Comment: @EuYu The fact that the name was "given by Verhulst" does not explain _why_ it was given. Usually people pick names for a reason, but maybe Verhulst was an exception.

Comment: From what I can tell, Verhulst wrote in French. I'm guessing that "logistic" here comes from _logistique_ in French which in turn derives from "to lodge" or "to house". The curve originally arose from the study of population growths so this seems like a reasonable interpretation to me. I would probably ask a linguist to be sure.

Comment: Ok, I looked at the French wikipedia, which states "Le nom de courbe logistique leur a été donné par Verhulst sans que l'on sache exactement pourquoi." - "The name "logistic curve" was given to it by Verhulst, but no one knows exactly why". The reference $href=http://rasch.org/rmt/rmt64k.htm$ gives the following commentary:

Comment: Verhulst writes "We will give the name logistic [logistique] to the curve" (1845 p.8). Though he does not explain this choice, there is a connection with the logarithmic basis of the function. Logarithm was coined by John Napier (1550-1617) from Greek logos (ratio, proportion, reckoning) and arithmos (number). Logistic comes from the Greek logistikos (computational). In the 1700's, logarithmic and logistic were synonymous. Since computation is needed to predict the supplies an army requires, logistics has come to be also used for the movement and supply of troops.

Comment: So it appears the other meaning of "logistics" comes from the same logic as Verhulst terminology, but is independent (?). Verhulst paper is [accessible](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN129323640_0018&DMDID=dmdlog7); the definition is on page 8 (page 21 in the volume), and the picture is after the article (page 54 in the volume).

Comment: See the post : [source of logistic growth](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/5499/source-of-logistic-growth).

Comment: According to the book Topics in Mathematical Modeling, by K. K. Tung, *Verhulst called this solution the "logistic curve." The French term "logistique" was used to signify the art of calculation.*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Cite [max](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/2633/max)

> The fact that the name was "given by Verhulst" does not explain why it was given. Usually people pick names for a reason, but maybe Verhulst was an exception. Ok, I looked at the French wikipedia, which states "Le nom de courbe logistique leur a été donné par Verhulst sans que l'on sache exactement pourquoi." - "The name "logistic curve" was given to it by Verhulst, but no one knows exactly why". The reference [rasch.org](http://rasch.org/rmt/rmt64k.htm) gives the following commentary:
>
> "Verhulst writes "We will give the name logistic [logistique] to the curve" (1845 p.8). Though he does not explain this choice, there is a connection with the logarithmic basis of the function. Logarithm was coined by John Napier (1550-1617) from Greek logos (ratio, proportion, reckoning) and arithmos (number). Logistic comes from the Greek logistikos (computational). In the 1700's, logarithmic and logistic were synonymous. Since computation is needed to predict the supplies an army requires, logistics has come to be also used for the movement and supply of troops. So it appears the other meaning of "logistics" comes from the same logic as Verhulst terminology, but is independent (?). Verhulst paper is [accessible](http://resolver.sub.uni-goettingen.de/purl?PPN129323640_0018); the definition is on page 8 (page 21 in the volume), and the picture is after the article (page 54 in the volume). "

Comment: Good explanation, especially for the latter half!

Comment: The Rasch reference (by John M. Linacre) confuses several loosely related words. The connection with *logarithm* is speculative; they're both from λόγος (*lógos*), but λογιστικός (*logistikós*) was an Ancient Greek word, while *logarithm* was a modern coinage. Also, *logistics* (*logistique*) was an 1830 French military term, derived from *logis* (lodgings), and presumably unrelated (a mathematician would more likely draw from Greek mathematical terms, rather than new military terms).

Answer (score 9):

(Cross-posted from *History of Science and Mathematics*: [source of “logistic growth”?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/7875/8002))

As stated above, the term *[logistic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/logistic)* is due to the Belgian mathematician [Pierre François Verhulst](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Fran%C3%A7ois_Verhulst), who invented the [logistic growth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_growth) model, and named it *logistic* (French: *[logistique](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/logistique)*) in his 1845 "Recherches mathématiques sur la loi d'accroissement de la population", [p. 8](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN129323640_0018?tify=%7B%22pages%22:%5B21%5D,%22view%22:%22info%22%7D):

> Nous donnerons le nom de *logistique* à la courbe
>
> > We will give the name *logistic* to the curve

He does not explain why he uses this term, but it is presumably by analogy with *arithmetic* and *geometric*, and in contrast to *logarithmic*, as in [figure](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN129323640_0018?tify=%7B%22pages%22:%5B54%5D,%22panX%22:0.487,%22panY%22:0.616,%22view%22:%22info%22,%22zoom%22:0.592%7D) below (from the original paper).

The French term *logistique* is from Ancient Greek λογιστικός (logistikós, “practiced in arithmetic; rational”), from λογίζομαι (logízomai, “I reason, I calculate”), from λόγος (lógos, “reason, computation”), whence English *logos*, *logic*, *logarithm*, etc. In Ancient Greek mathematics, *logistikós* was a division of mathematics: practical computation and accounting, in contrast to ἀριθμητική (arithmētikḗ), the theoretical or philosophical study of numbers. Confusingly, today we call practical computation *arithmetic*, and don't use *logistic* to refer to computation.

Verhulst first discusses the [arithmetic growth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_growth) and [geometric growth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_growth) models, referring to arithmetic *progression* and geometric *progression*, and calling the geometric growth curve a *logarithmic* curve (confusingly, the modern term is instead *exponential* curve, which is the inverse), then follows with his new model of "logistic" growth, which is presumably named by analogy, after a traditional division of mathematics, and in contrast to the logarithmic curve. The term *logarithm* is itself derived as *log-arithm*, from Ancient Greek λόγος (*lógos*) and ἀριθμός (*arithmós*), the sources respectively of *logistic* and *arithmetic*.

There is no connection with *[logistics](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/logistics)* (1830), which is instead from *logis* (lodging), and was military jargon.

[image: Graph of logistic curve, contrasted with logarithmic curve, Verhulst 1845]